# jQuery hide dropdown box if select option contains one entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a dropdown box if the select option contains only one entry. (like below) I only want to hide the first drop downbox in this case whilst the second box should remain visible.

```
<div class="dropdown-filter-div">
<select>
<option value="">Gifts/Offers</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-filter-div">
<select>
<option value="">Gifts/Offers</option>
<option value="Gift">Gift</option>
<option value="Gift">Gift</option>
<option value="Gift">Gift</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I don't know how to start it though, here's what I want to do.. (I also have two of these in different tabs on the page in question.

```
if ($(".dropdown-filter-div > select > option")) contains 1 option {
  $(".dropdown-filter-div > select).hide();
});
```

EDIT

http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-6s-plus-128gb-rose-gold-deals/ mobile version (need a user agent switcher) with a popular mobile user agent to view problem.

Currently using @Kim Gysen

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $el = $('.dropdown-filter > select > option'); 
  console.log($el.length); 
  if($el.length == 1){
      $el.parent().hide(); 
  }
});
```

at the end of jq-assets.js but its not working. @Kim Gysen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to remove the entire select list from the div if that select list has 1 or less options.  So this is what I did to get it to work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown-filter-div">
        <select>
            <option value="">2</option>
            <option value="">Gifts/Offers</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-filter-div">
        <select>
            <option value="">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-filter-div">
        <select>
            <option value="">3</option>
            <option value="">Gifts/Offers</option>
            <option value="">Gifts/Offers</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allSelects = $('.dropdown-filter-div > select');

    allSelects.each(function(){
        if(this.length <= 1){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I probably took your answer too far, but this will select only those select lists that were smaller than or equal to 1 option and hide them.

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly.  If you just want to hide the first one only you could add the following:

var index = 0; //above allselects.each...; then add inside the if the following: 

if(this.length <= 1 && index == 0)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var $el = $('.dropdown-filter > select > option'); 
console.log($el.length); 
if($el.length == 1){
    $el.parent().hide(); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5536/

Comment: I have added that code to my site but its not working? do you have useragent switcher?

Comment: @Scott Did you check the fiddle? If it doesn't work on your site, there must be something else. The code above should work in all browsers supported by jQuery.

Comment: its a wordpress site the syntax has to be changed I think

Comment: http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-6s-plus-128gb-rose-gold-deals/ mobile version (need a user agent switcher with a popular mobile user agent

Comment: jQuery should work on your mobile. Since this code is executed on page load, make sure that the DOM is ready before applying the code.

Comment: I'm using jQuery I have added more info to the question I have added your code to the end of my file jq-assets.js but it doesn't seem to work although it does in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".dropdown-filter-div > select > option").length == 1 ) {
  $(".dropdown-filter-div > select).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
var items = $('.dropdown-filter-div').find('select');
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        if (item.options.length == 1)
            $(item).hide();
    });
```